# Particles reappear at emitter after dying

Tags: particles, collision

I am trying to animate a cascading device where particles are emitted from a rectangular plate in order to hit a bent plate which kills the particles. The particles are killed just fine upon collision with the bent plate, but after dying, they reappear as stationary objects on the emitting rectangular plate.

It is worth noting that this only happens in the rendered version of the animation - the viewport displays it just fine.

I've uploaded a sequence of a couple of the frames around the critical part in the animation.

Any idea as to why this happens and how to fix it?

[image: Image sequence showing how the particle collide with the bent plate and reappear at the rectangular emitter plate]

Comment: Make sure *Particle Settings > Render > Extra > Dead* is **not** checked.

Comment: It is not checked :/ If it was: Wouldn't that cause the dead particles to be stuck at the collision object? My problem is that the dead particles appear at the emitting object.

Comment: Was this ever solved? IM having the same thing happen in my renders

Comment: No, I never managed to get it solved. I worked around it by making the particles disappear after a set time, but it's not a nice solution and it takes a while to work through all the steps, timing the disappearance of the particles.